# MAX1771 not boosting voltage

Tags: boost, switching-regulator

I have made the below circuit using the [MAX1771](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/power/switching-regulators/MAX1771.html), but it does not work as intended. There is no increase in voltage at the output. It just outputs VIN minus diode drop at “CDI_TEST_HV”, as expected if it was turned off.

I have tried to eliminate R14 and tie it straight to ground. I have made a few scope images as well.

Can you please have a look at my circuit and see if there is anything obviously wrong?

[image: schematic diagram]

---

This is measured at the gate of Q2.

[image: scope trace at gate of Q2]

---

This is measured at L2. Basically the same at both sides of the component.

[image: scope image at L2]

---

**More investigation** shows the following measurements on the different pins:
1: 0.518 V
2: 12 - 23.9 V
3: 125 mV and reducing quickly
4: 3.4 mV
5: 1.503 V
6: 3.4 mV
7: 3.4 mV
8: 3.4 mV

It's interesting that sometimes it steps up to 24 V.

Comment: What is your desired output voltage? I assume 200V? Is the load connected to the ciruit, if yes, what are the load parameters? Can you do scopes of the FB Pin input and of the CS pin?

Comment: Output voltage in the 300-400V is desired. The only "load" is the capacitors in the circuit. I will try to make some more scopes.

Comment: Didnt get any useful scope pictures on those pins, but did some measurements. Please see addition to original post.

Comment: Are you measuring 23.9V on the Pin2 of the IC? If yes, this is bad. Absolute Maximum Rating is 17V, the IC could be damaged with higher Voltage